# Apache Camel reading unread mail from gmail account

Tags: java, email, apache-camel, pooling

Just tried learning Apache Camel.

I am trying to read gmail inbox unread mail.

I got the code snippet while searching but not able to get success from it.

if someone point out the mistake,

```
    PollingConsumer pollingConsumer = null;
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

   Endpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("imaps://imap.gmail.com?username=" + mailId + "&password=" + password + "&delete=false&peek=false&unseen=true&consumer.delay=6000&closeFolder=false&disconnect=false");


    System.out.println("end point:"+endpoint);

    pollingConsumer = endpoint.createPollingConsumer();
    System.out.println("polling consumer:"+pollingConsumer);
    pollingConsumer.start();

    pollingConsumer.getEndpoint().createExchange();
    System.out.println("Exchange is created:");
    Exchange exchange = pollingConsumer.receive();
    System.out.println("pollingConsumer.receive()");
```

`pollingConsumer.receive();` is getting blocked, I have unread mail in my mailbox.
Also I tried `pollingConsumer.receive(6000);` but it returns null.

I enable IMAP access in Gmail settings. is there any thing I am missing?

Comment: Are you running this behind a proxy?

Comment: Your code works for me. The problem is outside camel.

Comment: Thanks Itsallas and James for help. I wrote the solution. It was mistake from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write the solution, It will help someone facing similar issue .

Actually I have added java mail jar, but imap jar was missing and it was not displaying any error for this.

That is why I was not able to figure out the actual cause.

After browsing the parameters of `"imaps://imap.gmail.com"`, I came across `"debugMode"` parameter which by default is false. when I added that parameter with value true, then it complained of missing jar on my console. After adding that jar thinks work perfectly.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What JDK, OS and application server are you using? And is it the imap.jar from com.sun.mail (http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.sun.mail%22%20AND%20a%3A%22imap%22) ?